# Matching alternative regexps in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python to parse a file in search for e-mail addresses, but I can't figure out what the syntax for alternative regexps should be. Here's the code:

```
addresses = []

pattern = '(\w+)@(\w+\.com)|(\w+)@(it.\w+\.com)'
for line in file:
    matches = re.findall(pattern,line)
    for m in matches:
        address = '%s@%s' % m
        addresses.append(address)
```

So I want to find addresses that look like john@company.com or john@it.company.com, but the above code doesn't work because either the first two groups are empty or the last two groups are empty. What is the correct solution? I need to use groups to store the user name (before @) and server name (after @) separately.

EDIT: Matching email adresses is only an example. What I'm trying to find out is how to match different regexps that have only one thing in common - they match two groups.

Comment: You should use `rx = re.compile(pattern)` once at the start, and then use `rx.findall(line)` so that its more efficient and not compiling the regex each time.

Comment: @jdi: Not necessary, Python caches the last 100 regexes you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(\w+)@((?:it\.)?\w+\.com)`

You want to capture the part after the `@` whether it's `example.com` or `it.example.com`, so you put both options inside the same capture group.  But since they share a similar format, you can condense `(it\.\w+\.com|\w+\.com)` to just `((it\.)?\w+\.com)`

The `(?: )` makes that parens a non-capturing group, so it won't take part in your matched groups.  There will be one match for the first `(\w+)`, and one match for the whole `((?:it\.)?\w+\.com)` after the `@`.  That's two matches total, plus the default group-0 match for the full string.

EDIT: To answer your new question, all you have to do is follow the grouping I used, but stop before you condense it.
If your test cases are:

1) `example@abcdef`

2) `example@123456`

You could write your regex as such: `(\w+)@([a-zA-Z]+|\d+)`, which would always have the part before the `@` in group 1, and the part after in group 2.  Notice that there are only two pairs of parens, and the `|`("or") operator appears inside of the second parens group.

Comment: But then I get three different groups instead of two.

Comment: No you dont. you get two groups. The result of findall will be: `[(name, host), (name, host), ...]`

Comment: True, but then again this is a bit of a workaround of what I want to achieve. I'll edit my question to make it more clearer

Answer (score 2):

I once found [here](https://github.com/minitech/EmailRegex) a well written email regex, it was build for extracting a wide range of valid email adresses from a generic string, so it should also be able to do what you're looking for.

Example:

```py
>>> email_regex = re.compile("""((([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~]+|"([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~(),:;<>@\[\]\.]|\\[ \\"])*")\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~]+|"([a-zA-Z0-9!\#\$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~(),:;<>@\[\]\.]|\\[ \\"])*"))@((([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*)?\.)*[a-zA-Z]+|\[((0?\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(0?\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]|\[[Ii][Pp][vV]6(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){6}\]))""")
>>>
>>> m = email_regex.search('john@it.company.com')
>>> m.group(0)
'john@it.company.com'
>>> m.group(1)
'john'
>>> m.group(7)
'it.company.com'
>>>
>>> n = email_regex.search('john@company.com')
>>> n.group(0)
'john@company.com'
>>> n.group(1)
'john'
>>> n.group(7)
'company.com'
```